# Can we have two entries in AMConfig.properties for `com.iplanet.am.server.host`?

Tags: openam, opensso

Can we have two entries in AMConfig.properties `com.iplanet.am.server.host`?
eg.
`com.iplanet.am.server.host=server1.example.com,server1.example.info`

OR

```
com.iplanet.am.server.host=server1.example.com
com.iplanet.am.server.host=server1.example.info
```

If not, how can we configure two identity_servers?

Update:  Just one OpenAM instance servicing multiple FQDNs.

Comment: What does 
"can we configure two identity_servers?"
mean? Two OpenAM instances, or just one OpenAM instance servicing multiple FQDNs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 entries for `com.iplanet.am.server.host` in `AMConfig.properties`.

You just need to configure an fqdnMap entry

```
com.sun.identity.server.fqdnMap[server1.example.info]=server1.example.info
```

as advanced server property. However please keep in mind that in your case the two FQDNs do not share a common cookie domain. From cookie security point of view you should use host-based cookies anyway by removing all cookie domains from OpenAM's platform service (global configuration). If you still want to use domain cookies, make sure to have cookie domains

```
example.info
example.com
```

set in platform service. Make sure you understand ['cookie spec'](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)